# Batgirl - Robin - Batman love triangle

Tags: batman, dc, the-killing-joke-2016

It's known that Batgirl (Barbara Gordon) and Robin (Dick Grayson) have an on-off relationship. But in the animated movie, *The Killing Joke*, Batgirl sleeps with Batman.

This may seem like a stupid question, but - does Robin know about this? Did it affect their relationship in any way?

Comment: Some people think its even more of a triangle than that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_in_the_Batman_franchise

Comment: It's worth to note that the Batgirl-Batman relationship in *The Killing Joke* is entirely a product of the film adaptation and *not* part of the original comic.

Comment: Yeah, my first reaction was: "I own a copy of that graphic novel, and Batman didn't sleep with Barbara in it." My second reaction was to realize that the OP must be talking about the film adaptation, which I haven't seen. A word of advice, krishna -- you might want to be more specific the next time you ask about a plot point. For instance, specifying whether you're talking about a comic book, or a film on DVD, or a TV episode, or whatever, and its year of release, instead of just briefly mentioning a title such as "The Killing Joke" and hoping everyone will know exactly what you mean. :-)

Comment: In the DCAU Batman and Batgirl date, per Batman Beyond.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach thanks that makes more sense.

Comment: The _real_ triangle is between Batman, Jim Gordon, & the Joker.

Comment: Well going here: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Hush we get to know the story of a certain comic book where Batman and Catwoman kiss. I believe that this may be more of a triquetra.